# How to setup a dbConfigFile for robotframework to be able to hold different databases connections?

Tags: database, database-connection, robotframework

We are trying to setup robotframework in our organization. We got the basic suite up and running . But we would like to have all the different database connections sit in a db.cfg file and gets called depending on the tests rather than hard coding them in the tests. Would like to know how i will have the db.cfg setup for two different databases. The parameters that i use right now for connections are user,pwd,dsn . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use robot variables or a python object to contain your connection information (eg: `${DB_USER}`, or `${DB.USER}`). You can then set these from the command line, from an argument file, or from a variable file.

### Command line

You can directly set variables on the command line. For example:

```
robot --variable DB_DSN:mysql://staging.mycompany.com:3306/my_db \
    --variable DB_USER:db_user --variable DB_PWD superSecret! tests/*.robot
```

### Argument file

Argument files let you collect a group of command line options into a single file, and then include them with the command line argument `--argumentfile`.

For example, you could create a file named "staging.args" or "production.args" that you can use to define the variables:

```
# staging.args
--variable  DB_DSN:mysql://staging.mycompany.com:3306/my_db
--variable  DB_USER:db_user
--variable  DB_PWD: superSecret!

# production.args
--variable  DB_DSN:mysql://mycompany.com:3306/prod_db
--variable  DB_USER:prod_db_user
--variable  DB_PWD: SuperSecret!
```

You can then use the `--argumentfile` option when running your tests to specify which variables to use:

```
robot --argumentfile staging.args  tests/*.robot
```

Argument files are documented in the robot framework user guide in a section titled [Argument Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#argument-files)

### Variable file

A variable file is python code that can set variables. The convenient thing about variable files is it allows you to use the features of python to set variables, such as conditional logic.

For example, you could create a file named "site-config.py" that looks like this:

```
# site-config.py
def get_variables(environment):
    return db_config[environment]

db_config = {
    "production": {
        "DB_DSN":  "mysql://mycompany.com:3306/prod_db",
        "DB_USER": "prod_db_user",
        "DB_PWD":  "SuperSecret!"
    },
    "staging": {
        "DB_DSN":  "mysql://staging.mycompany.com:3306/my_db",
        "DB_USER": "db_user",
        "DB_PWD":  "superSecret!"
    }        
}
```

You can then pass in the environment as an argument with the `--variablefile` option:

```
robot --variablefile site-config:production tests/*.robot
```

The string "production" will be passed in as an argument to `get_variables`, which then returns the appropriate set of variables as a dictionary.

This is documented in the robot framework user guide in the section titled [Variable Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files).

### Using python objects in a variable file

You could also use a python object rather than a dictionary to store the config information. For example, you could define your variable file like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def get_variables(environment):
    return {
        "dbconfig": db_config[environment]
    }

DBConfig = namedtuple('DBCONFIG', 'dsn, user, pwd')
db_config = {
    "production": DBConfig("mysql://mycompany.com:3306/prod_db", "prod_db_user", "SuperSecret!"),
    "staging":    DBConfig("mysql://staging.mycompany.com:3306/my_db", "db_user", "superSecret!"),
}
```

With the above, you end up with a variable named `${dbconfig}` which you can use with dot notation to get the values: `${dbconfig.dsn}`, `${dbconfig.user}`, `${dbconfig.pwd}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have a demo coming up and I wanted to avoid the credentials hard coded. Will give this a try and respond. Thanks again.

Comment: In between the separate argument files, and the Python variable file sits the [YAML variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-file-as-yaml). The upside is that it doesn't use Python code and creates dot notation variables. The down side is that there is no flexibility which variables are returned. A large tree is always returned and you still need a command line variable to highlight which part of the tree you need and fetch it yourself.

Comment: @bryan  I was able to successfully set python obj file for different databases . However i had to use ${test['dbconfig'].user}  where $test is my variable which stores get_variable function value.